# Kendo UI Grid display multiple fileds in single column

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display multiple fields in a single cell in an ASP.NET MVC Kendo Razor grid

I've tried both

`columns.Template(@<text>@item.Field1 @item.Field2</text>).Title("Test");`

and

`columns.Bound(c => new {x = c.Field1, y = c.Field2}).Template(@<text><strong>@item.Field1 @item.Field2</strong></text>).Title("Test");`

Does anyone have any expereience of how this can be done?

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(modelData[i])
          .Name($"grid{i}")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.Field1).Title("Column1");

              //These don't work!
              columns.Template(@<text>@item.Field1 @item.Field2</text>).Title("Test");
              columns.Bound(c => new {x = c.Field1, y = c.Field2}).Template(@<text><strong>@item.Field1 @item.Field2</strong></text>).Title("Test");
          })
          .Sortable(sortable =>
          {
              sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn);
          })
          .Filterable()
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(20)
              .ServerOperation(false)
          )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about trying to append the two strings together within a [`ClientTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#clienttemplate)?

```
.Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Field1).Title("Column1");
          columns.Bound(product => c.Field2).ClientTemplate("<strong>#: Field1 #</strong>#: Field2 #");
      })
```

Note: The `Bound` field specified will be used for sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show the field value You can use the `ClientTemplate` with following syntax:

```
columns.ClientTemplate("<span>#=Field1 #</span><span>#=Field2 #</span>").Title("Test");
```